# Google PDF Viewer default fit to width embed

Tags: html, pdf, embed

When I embed a pdf using google's PDF viewer

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=http://jugglegood.com/out/scot-nery-resume-grand.pdf"  ></iframe>
```

it defaults to displaying the pdf with a lot of space around it.

[image]

Then, I click the + magnify (zoom) button at the bottom of the viewer and it zooms to fit to width.

[image]

Is there a way to default using parameters or something to the fit to width zoom version of the embed?  I couldn't find an answer, so i even tried using jquery to manually click the zoom button... no dice.

Comment: Yes, please! Looking for this as well!

Comment: Me too, please! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

here are some ideas:

1. check your CSS to see if there are any settings for a class, id, iframe - your stylesheet could be telling the browser how to display the PDF on screen.
2. You can tell the iframe in the HTML to be 100% width. I run into this a lot for Google Maps hosted on a site.

```
    <iframe src="https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=http://jugglegood.com/out/scot-nery-resume-grand.pdf" width="100%" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0"></iframe>
```

I keep the aria-hidden [this is for screen readers for people who are blind] and tabindex [keyboard navigation for people with disabilites]. Pleasee see my GitHub WAPS system for website code and design for people with diverse needs.